# C++ Array subscripting differences

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array declared like this

```
float dati[10];
```

I normally subscript the array like as follows

```
dati[2] = 5;
```

But i have also seen other types of substriptions like

```
2[dati] = 5;
```

and

```
*(dati+2) = 5;
```

Can anyone tell me what's the difference between these three?

Comment: There's no difference. They all get rewritten to the 3rd version.

Comment: Please never use the second in production code, on pain of gross misconduct dissmisal :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler translates `a[i]` as `*(a+i)`, so this bit links up your first and third manner of indexing.

Now, `a` being the address of first element of an array - aka a pointer - and `i` being an integral constant or variable you know `a + i` is the same thing as `i + a`. This means the following also holds

```
a[2] = *(a + 2) = *(2 + a) = 2[a]
```

So all three are equivalent ways of accessing the third element of an array.